# PSU - grounding - charging AGM batteries

Tags: power-supply, batteries, grounding, charging

I'm using a Flatpack2HE frontend 3000 W 48 V PSU for charging an AGM battery bank from a 240V AC  generator (or at least that's the plan).

It's an off grid solar power system in the UK, generator is going to be used as a backup for when solar is insufficient.

https://www.eltek.com/uk/products/flatpack2-483000-he/

The label on the PSU states "High leakage current: earth connection essential before connecting supply".

Sadly an earth connection is not currently available at the off grid site

What are the dangers of running without earth connection, is it just electric shock when touching the PSU casing, or is there possible or damage to equipment?

All help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> What are the dangers of running without earth connection

Dying. If you manage to kill someone else, prosecution for manslaughter.

> Sadly an earth connection is not currently available at the off grid site

You can either engineer the system to code as an isolated installation, including the use of equipment that doesn't need an earth, or install an earth connection. I suggest the latter.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the dangers of running without earth connection

That you get a tingle sensation or even a mild shock when you touch the metal enclosure or one of the DC leads. That may be enough to hurt a child.

> possible or damage to equipment?

Not to the power devices. It could damage some unrelated, sensitive device that may come in accidental contact between the case and the ground under your feet.

> I'm using a ... PSU for charging an AGM battery bank

Not a good idea. To charge a battery, use a charger, not a power supply.

- A CCCV charger is current limited and has the correct top voltage.
- A power supply has an undefined behavior when connected to a discharged battery and may even be damaged; also, generally it won't let you adjust the top voltage.

Comment: Is that possible AC leakage down the DC lines ?       The trouble is we're 48v & proper AGM chargers are very expensive , £1,000+ at this size.    ...       We're going to adjust the top voltage by CANbus ,      this also has a set-able max current ...   https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-405-charging-with-a-power-supply .     Saying all that , I am not an expert at all , but I have done some research , I'm not sure this is going to work ....  all help appreciated

Comment: Also this AGM battery system has a max charge current of 60amps @ 48v , 2.9kwh , roughly the same as the max output of the PSU

Comment: OK, but what happens if the battery is discharged? Will the PSU run at 60 A? Will it foldback the current to 30 A? Will it put out 40 A and blow up? That's usually not specified. That's why for charging we use a charger, not a PSU.

Comment: "Is that possible AC leakage down the DC lines ?". Yes, through an internal capacitor between the AC side and the DC side.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am selling it , and sourcing a suitable charger .